# Using array the objects the class abstract

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, abstract

i have 1 problem, I can not open my method , I do not well downcast.
i have 3 class, and 1 is abstract.

```
public abstract class Canideos {
    public abstract String ladrar();
}

public class Gato extends Canideos{
    @Override
    public String ladrar() {
        String ladrar="miau miau";
       return ladrar;
    }    
    public String miar(){
    String mi="miau a miau";
            return mi;
    }    
}
```

And my drive is this:

```
Canideos cani[]= {new Cao(), new Gato()}; // it works :)
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            System.out.println(cani[i].ladrar());
        }
String a;
```

my problem is this: :/

```
a = (String) cani[1].Gato().miar();
a = cani[1].miar();
```

I can not open the method miar() the class Gato.

Comment: [`a = ((Gato)cani[1]).miar();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html#Footer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for downcasting a superclass instance to a subclass instance is similar to regular casting:

```
Gato gato = (Gato) cani[1];
a = gato.miar();
```

Or equivalently, just:

```
a = ((Gato) cani[1]).miar();
```

Note the additional parentheses in the second case. They are just used for precedence purposes, otherwise it would be parsed as `(Gato) (cani[1].miar())` trying to cast the result of `miar` to a `Gato`.

Comment: Thank you all !!! I had tried but had a For Each , and was not working ...
    for(Canideos a:cani){
            System.out.println("# "+a.ladrar());
       }
    }

 a = ((Gato) cani[1]).miar();

after the For Each , not working...